# How to use the widget fullpath to access widget's properties?

Tags: google-app-maker

I know that using widget.getFullPath() method, we can retrieve the full path of a widget as a string in the format "pagename.child1name.child2name....childNname.widgetname".
I am trying to find a way for using this string to access the original widget.
I was successful using this:

app.pages["pagename"].children["child1name"].children["child2name"]....children["childNname"].children["widgetname"].text = "some text";

but I don't know how to change this in a more general function, independent by the depth of  the path.
Any idea would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The parent root descendents should have everything on the page, so try:

```
widget.parent.root.descendants.ANYTHING.value;
```

you might alternately need to do this if you want ANYTHING to be a variable

```
widget.parent.root.descendants[ANYTHING].value;
```

Comment: J.G., thank you for your answer, but it doesn't address my question. My question asks how to change the string returned by the method widget.getFullPath() in a usable object.

Answer (score 0):

My intention is to access the widget's property from another page. The root of a widget is its page, and it is the string before the first dot in the full path.
I eventually wrote a function which builds the object after splitting the full path string in an array:

```
function getWidgetPath(pathString) {
  var pathArray = pathString.split('.');
  var widgetPath = app.pages[pathArray[0]];
  for( i=1; i<pathArray.length; i++ ) {
    widgetPath = widgetPath.children[pathArray[i]];
  }
  return widgetPath;
}
```

The function can be used to build the target object. I.e., considering that the target widget is a label and I want to change its text property, I use:

```
var targetPath = 'parentpage.panel1.panel2.panel3.label1';
var targetWidget = getWidgetPath(targetPath);
targetWidget.text = 'some text';
```

I have the feeling that it's not very Javascriptian, though.